# Changing imageview on button click android

Tags: android

I'm attempting to to change the image when the button is clicked. In the learning curve at the moment so having trouble identifying why its failing.

Here's my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button changeMebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeMe);

    changeMebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.amsterdam);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lima);
        }
    });


}
```

}

XML:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/amsterdam" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Me" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

I'm currently getting an generic error when i click the button.

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong here...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

use

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lima);
```

instead of

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.amsterdam);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lima);
```

because your image id is imageView1 in xml not amsterdam

and second point use `R.id.imageView1` instead of `R.drawable.amsterdam`

Comment: @LalitPoptani : sir,i have already mention two lines after code which clearing indicating what is problem in current code because he is passing a drawable id in `findViewById instead of `ImageView` id means he is casting a `Drawable` to `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I knew was missing something by not utilizing the 'imageView1'. just failed to internalize...

Comment: This solution only be applied for which applications have single instance of R.drawable.amsterdam.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```